# OpenDS - Unable to uninstall

Tags: opends

I installed OpenDS on Windows 7 under C:\Users\ on port 389. (Admin privileges available)

However, I am unable to uninstall it. (I've tried using command line, GUI, stop-ds.bat, Killing the windows service, running as Administrator)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you failed to unregister the Windows service.

Otherwise, uninstalling OpenDS is as simple as simply deleting the whole installation directory